# Scrapy inconsisent number of items scraped with callbacks and following links

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm crawling yellow pages results and getting an inconsistent number of scraped items when trying to follow both the yellow pages entries as well as the pagination links. I believe I have 2 issues, but I seem to be able to work around the first. Hopefully this workaround is not causing my second issue.

I have no problem getting the 121 search results I expect from [here](https://www.paginasamarillas.es/search/administrador-de-fincas/all-ma/zaragoza/all-is/zaragoza/all-ba/all-pu/all-nc/1?what=Administrador%20de%20fincas&where=Zaragoza). I do this based on [this example](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-for-creating-requests) from the official tutorial:

```
class LinksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "links"
    start_urls = [
        r"https://www.paginasamarillas.es/search/administrador-de-fincas/all-ma/zaragoza/all-is/zaragoza/all-ba/all-pu/all-nc/1?what=Administrador%20de%20fincas&where=Zaragoza",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for comercial in response.css('div.col-xs-11.comercial-nombre .row a'):
            href = comercial.attrib["href"]
            if '#' not in href:
                print('href = ', href)
                yield {
                    'name': comercial.css('h2 span::text').get(),
                    'link': href,
                }

        list_items = response.css('ul.pagination li')
        for li in list_items:
            anchor = li.css('a')
            i = anchor.css('i')
            if len(i) != 0:
                next_page = anchor.attrib['href']
                print('next_page = ', next_page)

        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

So my first issue is having to create the for loop involving the `list_items` as a workaround to get the `next_page`. This is because the button that takes you to the next page is not `li > a` like the shortcuts to pages 1, 2, ..., 5. The next page button is the only one with an `<i>` inside the `<a>`, that is `li > a > i`. Ideally I would do something like

```
for href in response.xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[31]/ul/li[6]/a/i/../@href'):
    yield response.follow(href, self.parse)
```

but for some reason that `div[5]` is not found, although `div[4]` is. According to my research, a potential reason could be because that 5th div is generated by javascript and doesn't yet exist by the time the spider fetches the html. I doubt this is the real reason because I am able to see the div when I save the response into an html file. In any case, the workaround correctly results in the expected 121 items:

```
2020-02-17 17:37:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-02-17 17:37:07 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (121 items) in: links.json
```

Assuming this workaround isn't messing with my next steps, I am ok with it and would like to focus on my second issue. In order to follow each yellow pages entry to gather each entry's info, I imitate the [example](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#more-examples-and-patterns) in the tutorial:

```
class FullSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "full"
    start_urls = [
        r"https://www.paginasamarillas.es/search/administrador-de-fincas/all-ma/zaragoza/all-is/zaragoza/all-ba/all-pu/all-nc/1?what=Administrador%20de%20fincas&where=Zaragoza",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for comercial in response.css('div.col-xs-11.comercial-nombre .row a'):
            href = comercial.attrib["href"]
            # sleep(1)
            if '#' not in href:
                print('href = ', href)
                yield response.follow(href, self.parse_comercial, meta={'link': href})

        list_items = response.css('ul.pagination li')
        for li in list_items:
            anchor = li.css('a')
            i = anchor.css('i')
            if len(i) != 0:
                next_page = anchor.attrib['href']
                print('next_page = ', next_page)

        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_comercial(self, response):

        def extract_with_css(query):
            return response.css(query).get(default='').strip()

        yield {
            'name': extract_with_css('div.titular > h1::text'),
            'link': response.meta.get('link'),
            'sitioWeb': extract_with_css('div.botonesCta > a:not([id^="cfContacta"])::attr(href)'),
        }
```

This produces almost the exact results I want, except that, instead of 121, the number of items returned is sometimes 91, sometimes 94, etc.:

```
2020-02-17 18:01:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-02-17 18:01:50 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (94 items) in: full.json
```

My research hints at the asynchronous nature of these requests and/or yields (two different things, I know, but maybe one of them is the culprit) but slowing down (ie, adding `sleep()`) or simplifying the code (asking it to yield fewer keys) don't seem to improve things.

As I type this, I'm noticing a scrapy stat referencing duplicate filtering, but I'm not really able to make sense of these stats. I'll dump them here in case it helps anyone help me.

After the first spider and the correct 121 results:

```
2020-02-17 17:37:07 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 3167,
 'downloader/request_count': 5,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 5,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 134605,
 'downloader/response_count': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 5,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 4.895525,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 17, 16, 37, 7, 343129),
 'item_scraped_count': 121,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 127,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'request_depth_max': 5,
 'response_received_count': 5,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 5,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 5,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 5,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 5,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 17, 16, 37, 2, 447604)}
```

The second spider, with the inconsistent 90-94 results:

```
2020-02-17 18:01:50 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 62095,
 'downloader/request_count': 99,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 99,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2154817,
 'downloader/response_count': 99,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 99,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 28,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 9.433248,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 17, 17, 1, 50, 120636),
 'item_scraped_count': 94,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 194,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'request_depth_max': 5,
 'response_received_count': 99,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 99,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 99,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 99,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 99,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 17, 17, 1, 40, 687388)}
```

Sorry for the length, but I appreciate any hints. Thanks!

EDIT: The first issue (the workaround) seems to be solved thanks to @furas. Still struggling with the second issue (inconsistent results) though.

Comment: you could check only last element in pagination - `list_items[-1]` - to check if there is link to next page.

Comment: you should ask for one problem on page. Other problem should be on new page.

Comment: Good tip about `list_items[-1]`, ultimately I'm using your other suggestion based on `xpath()` so it isn't needed, but thanks.

About the 2 issues in one post, I thought the first might be affecting the second but I get your point.

Answer (score 1):

To get link to next page you can search `<a>` which has `<i>` with class `"fa icon-flecha-derecha"` which displays icon `>`. There can be other `<i>` with icon `<` so I have to use `class` to recognize correct icon.

Using `xpath` you can nest elements `a[ i[@class="fa icon-flecha-derecha"] ]` to get access to `<a>` instead of `<i>` and get `@href`

```
response.xpath('//ul[@class="pagination"]//li/a[i[@class="fa icon-flecha-derecha"]]/@href').get() #.getall()
```

---

As for 93 and 121.

I saved urls in file and used `pandas` to compare them.

There are 121 links but only 93 links are unique - some of them are repeated on web pages.

First code saves all urls (even repeated), second code saves only urls of visited pages - because `Scrapy` doesn't visit again the same page so it visits only 93 pages.

Comment: Thanks for the `xpath()` snippet, it really cleans up the code and I also learned something about nesting elements. The links spider is producing the 121 expected links.

However, the full spider is still inconsistent. Why is it producing, for example, 89 results in one run, 86 the next time I run it, then 84, then 93?

Comment: `2020-02-18 15:04:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-02-18 15:04:08 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (89 items) in: full.json`

`2020-02-18 15:04:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-02-18 15:04:32 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (86 items) in: full.json`

`2020-02-18 15:04:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-02-18 15:04:54 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (84 items) in: full.json`

Comment: `2020-02-18 15:05:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-02-18 15:05:14 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (93 items) in: full.json`

`2020-02-18 15:06:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-02-18 15:06:33 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (89 items) in: full.json`

Comment: I can see in the stats that it is dupefiltering different amounts each time, shouldn't the duplicates always be the same number?

Comment: I run it only few times and always get the same number. But maybe server has problem to send all data, or it send different data for some reason - ie. it may use two (or more) computers to send responses and some of them has old data. You would have to save all pages few times and compare them to see if they have different content.